# How to force Python not to fill with None

Tags: python

I am using SQL to get data from the SalesForce API using Python. The output is written to a CSV file.

When I check the CSV file, there are several null values that are written to the CSV file as "None".

Is there any way to force Python not to fill null values with None, or an option to treat nulls as empty strings instead of None.

Comment: Please show part of code where you are pulling data from SQL and writing them to csv.

Comment: Don't make people guess.  Show some code.

Comment: Could you it be that you need to look on why those Nones are problem for you downstream? It feels that it's standard way to have them and the way you manipulate data later is non-standard. Potentially it's better to alter how you process CSV later to make it compatible with other similar exports, rather than trying to tail data to your needs. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest using `pandas` to read the CSV before writing and `.fillna()` as a way to replace all the `None` values.

Comment: Am using JSON response and writing this result into csv file using CSV [link] (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

In this case, how i can do replace ?

Comment: You can also work directly with the CSV using `pandas`. It has `.fillna("")` function, that would replace all the `None`(`nan`) with what you pass into it.

Comment: This is a bit fragile; if the JSON is generated with different whitespace then it will break, and it's susceptible to changing the contents of string values in the JSON if they happen to contain `: null`.

Comment: Please don't suggest string replacement on the JSON directly. Those `null`s will be loaded as Python `None`s. The resulting data structure should be operated on, not the JSON text itself.